# What does it mean for a symbol to be absolute or relocatable?

Tags: assembly

According to [Assemblers And Loaders](http://www.davidsalomon.name/assem.advertis/AssemAd.html):

> In the case of a future symbol, the assembler does not know the type
>   (absolute or relocatable) of the missing symbol. It thus cannot
>   generate the relocation bit...

A future symbol is a symbol encountered before it has been declared. For example:

```
    JMP TO
    ...
TO: ADD 1,2
```

When the `JMP TO` instruction is assembled, the symbol `TO` is a future symbol, since its definition has not yet been encountered.

Since a symbol refers to a location in memory, how can it ever **not** be relocatable?

Comment: Hard to say without more context on what the book considers a `relocation bit` to be. At a guess the architectures employs different instruction encodings for absolute and relative addresses. If so then a relative offset might be emitted within a program, allowing arbitrary program relocation without fix-ups. Conversely if TO ends up referring to a ROM vector within the operating system at an absolute address (`TO equ $1000`) then an absolute addressing mode would be appropriate.

Comment: That is a very old-fashioned concern.  Well, the book isn't called "Assemblers, Linkers and Loaders".  Nobody uses a one-pass assembler anymore, that was only important back in the 60's when memory was a serious limit to what an assembler could do.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt go and read your book.  And I love that it talks about the history of assemblers and linkers, which it was doing at the time, correctly, but the tools are way better now.

You are pretty much right.  I think the notion there is that some instruction sets, no need to get specific to one, offer near versions of things or instructions that are by reference basically some offset applied to the program counter is where to reference thing or jump to.  And in some way also offer a way to use an absolute address either encoded in the (variable length) instruction, or can jump to an address in a register that was loaded from a location (pc relative) or through an immediate mov, etc.  I think what this author is implying is that once you hardcode that address it is fixed forever, absolute and the linker can never change it again.

Well it would only take me a few seconds to demonstrate what linkers can do today.  They can and will modify instructions and or generate the instruction needed rather than the assembler doing all instruction generation.  Even when you have the assembler do the whole thing you are still not stuck, well the assembler doesnt do the whole thing, the assembler would for example do a pc relative read of a location nearby, that location is know to the assembler and the linker to be the address of some label that is not in this object, an external.  The assembler writes all the CODE the near load into a register the jump to register, the linker fills in the address.  Once linked that appears like an absolute address but the linker could have relocated that and one could argue the binary format used can indicate that location is the address of some label so that even at load time a loader could change it.

Some instruction sets you can put the absolute address in the instruction and there is no real reason why the linker couldnt be responsible for filling in that portion of the instruction at link time.

I think the only problem situation would simply be bad design, is if within one object you have resolved a label and used a pc relative jump, but somehow the toolchain allows you to rip part of that object apart and separate it from the rest.  That would just be bad design.  One situation that the gnu tools at least handle quite nicely and no reason why others couldnt is take arm and thumb the bl instruction cannot change modes, so if not told otherwise the assembler assumes a bl to some label is going to be in the same mode because you the programmer used bl not blx or bx.  The linker comes along and finds that the label is in the other mode, if it can find space within reach it adds a trampoline a few instructions in the same mode that are functionally invisible (the return address is preserved, the mode is changed and the destination label/address is reached).  Really cool and I have posted examples of this here at SO.

The problem comes when the linker cannot find space it gets painted into a corner, it cannot make a trampoline, the instruction it needs to insert into the object wont fit and they cant trampoline within the rules of that instruction set, and then the linker has to bail out.  I think the threshold for bailing out today is a lot different than the threshold back then.  Even in the bl case above the gnu linkers and others were not that smart only a few versions ago, handful of years or less, they would bail out on that situation rather than just fix it.  I think in the arm case if you stay in the same mode and try to bl too far across the address space it will bail out rather than just fix it.  It could easily just fix that situation too.